# chrome.tabs.sendMessage doesn't pass on tabId to sender

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been experimenting with the chrome extension API and I noticed that the `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` doesn't pass on the `tabId` as the `sender` but another `id/` hash string that doesn't correspond with the `tabId`. Anyone that know why this is? Thanks.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage

Here is the code I'm running:

**manifest**

```
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
```

**event.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content-script.js"});
  sendMessageToContent;
});

function sendMessageToContent() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello", tab: tabs[0].id}, function(response) {
        });
      });
    }
```

**content-script.js**

```
console.log('script injected');

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.debug('tab', request.tab);
    console.debug('sender', sender);
  });
```

**Result:**

```
tab 1487
sender { id: "ldolkkbojegiehpmacmglfdlndkhlace" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [chrome.runtime API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-MessageSender): `sender.tab` and consequently `sender.tab.id` are present only when the message was sent from a normal tab, but you're sending from an extension popup which is a [separate extension page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch), not a tab. Hence `sender` contains the `id` of your own extension.

Comment: Yes you are definitely correct. Sender.id contains the id for the current background page: `chrome-extension://ldolkkbojegiehpmacmglfdlndkhlace/_generated_background_page.html`
It was my mistake to think passing the tabId would change the origin of the message. Thanks.

Comment: @ThinkTank I don't see how it's related. I think you should ask a new question with [MCVE](/help/mcve).